# My SQL, website 'unable to select database'

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I'm creating a My SQL database, I've created a database named `login` and the table name `login1`. Every time I try to load my page there is an error `unable to select database`, which I don't understand. In my last line of the config.php it says:

`$db = mysql_select_db($SETTINGS["login"], $connection) 
       or die ('request "Unable to select database."');
?>`

I can't see any other mistakes that I've made in the code.
Thanks

Comment: Give us your connection string.

Comment: You have to connect to the server before you can use this: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: mysql_select_db('database name') why do you have $SETTINGS

Comment: Make sure about the value of `$SETTINGS["login"]` and the database is exists with the name that you get in with `$SETTINGS["login"]`?

Comment: Give us full config.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must coonect to server like this.

```
// database connection info
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass") or    trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$db = mysql_select_db("databae",$conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
```

or better use PDO or MySQLi. Simple example:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die("Connection Problem" . mysqli_errno($con));
$database = mysqli_select_db($con, "database_name") or die("SQL Problem" . mysqli_error($con));
```

Or with PDO:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
   $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=database", $username, $password);
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   echo "Connected successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
   echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've used the PDO and it has started to work, however, at the very top of the screen of the login page this message appears: Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:9191' (1). - however I'm not sure what this is connected to as everything else is working fine.

Comment: Are you trying with `$servername="localhost:9191"` or just `$servername="localhost"`?

Comment: Also open `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and make sure that you have this there `127.0.0.1 localhost`. If you don't have it you must add it.